# how to specify a directoy as including header files directory

Tags: c, header-files, gnu, include-path

I don't want to use `-I` flags each time for including a header file I made before. I want to specify a directory and save header files there and make GNU gcc search there by default.

PS: I use windows and GNU 5.1.0.

Comment: That's a bad idea. Do what everyone else does, use some build system (in the simplest case a `Makefile` where you define e.g. an `INCLUDES` variable).

Comment: …and please spell properly.

Comment: You told what you do and what you don't want to do. Mind to ask a question? Best one which is not already covered by the Fine Manual?

Answer (score 0):

because of my low reputation I couldn't add comment,
I think you can use your own make file
learning from this link:

http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/

or this:

https://www.cs.oberlin.edu/~kuperman/help/make.html

or write your own script.

Comment: Maybe you can give a brief example on how to solve the problem in make. Then I would be tempted to give you an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

If all your header files are stored in the same directory, you need not include each .h file using -I option.
You can do something like

```
$(GCC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(HDR_INC_PATH) -c <source files>
```

where HDR_INC_PATH contains the path where your headers are stored.

If you have headers located in multiple locations, you can do something like

```
HDR_INC_PATH := -I<path1> \
                 -I<path2> \
                 -I<path3> \
                  and so on
```

where path1, path2 and path3 are the locations where the headers are located and use

```
$(GCC) $(CFLAGS) $(HDR_INC_PATH) -c <source files>
```

You can also make use of $(wildcard pattern) to search for all the header files in a directory. In this case you have to mention the top directory path so that headers in child directories are also taken.
Something like

```
HDR_FILES = $(wildcard <dir>/*.h)
```

where dir is the path of your parent directory. You can then make use $(HDR_FILES) with -I in your compiler recipe.